# Adding more tabs to horizontal navigation bar

Tags: headers

currently i'm using raindrops theme developing my page. Raindrops is using 
 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary'));
?>
to generate the horizontal navigation bar, which only shows a tab linked to posts->categories. I wish to add more tabs beside the original tab, such as faq, contact us etc. which can be linked to pages, posts or other url's etc, how can it done? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the “Appearance > Menus” screen in the admin area.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen